# Will upgrading node.js break ionic app & app then has to be resubmitted to app stores?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ionic-framework, ionic2, heroku-cli

Got an email from heroku to upgrade node.js for a security patch.

1) If I do that will it break my whole ionic application (ionic 2 beta 11) or not cause any problems?  I'm currently running node js v6.9.1 on the heroku app and I think I need to upgrade to 6.11.1.

It says I need to upgrade and commit even if the commit is empty by doing this:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "upgrade Node.js version"
$ git push heroku master
```

2) Since my app is on the android and apple app stores, do I need to then resubmit my app to both stores after this node.js upgrade or am I mixing apples and oranges this upgrade just deals with heroku and therefore I don't need to resubmit the app?

If someone can please give me some advice, I'm a bit stuck, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have your app's API on Heroku, am I right?

If so, your app doesn't need to be submitted to Apple/Google again.

As for your first question, I don't think there is any breaking change from 6.9.1 to 6.11.1 but if I were you, I'd check the update doc just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you! So my ionic app uses parse open server as a backend and that is hosted on heroku, not sure if that means its API is on heroku? So what you are saying is that it wouldn't create new bugs etc. in the front end ionic stuff, but could cause some problems then with parse and the backend if there was a breaking change? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. However, I just checked the release notes and there seem to be no breaking changes. If I were you, I'd do the update since it's a security release.